# Value and nature of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac {1}{3^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac {1}{3^n}$$ Find the sum and determine it's nature.

I have tried to find the limit of partial sums, but I could not do anything. There is another bunch of exercises of this type in front of me; can you please show me in detail how this exercise can be solved? Thank you.

Comment: This is a geometric series.  If you search on that term you should some information on summing them. I'm not sure what "nature" means in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, determine the general term $$a_n=-\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n$$
Next, it is often a good idea to calculate $\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}$.  In this case you get $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=-\frac{1}{3}$$
Now, if this is a constant, such as in this case, you have a geometric series.  If not, you can take its limit as $n\to \infty$ and use the ratio test to determine convergence (unless the limit is $1$).

Answer (score 3):

$$\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}\left(-1\right)^{n+1}\frac{1}{3^{n}}=-\underset{n\geq1}{\sum}\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^{n}=-\left(\underset{n\geq0}{\sum}\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^{n}-1\right)=\frac{1}{4}.$$Note that the geometric series starts from $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n+1} \cdot \frac {1}{3^n} $ is sum 
$-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a^n $ where $a=\left(\frac{-1}{3}\right)^n$
In theory of sum function that correspond to this sum is f(a)=-1/(1-a)+1.

Abel thm implies that sum  is f(-1/3)=-3/4.
You see here for more detail: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MaclaurinSeries.html
Yes, seris start from 1 than you have: sum = -3/4+1=1/4

Comment: What is this "Abel thm" you are referring to? (Surely you don't mean the usual [Abel's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel's_theorem))

Comment: Say about limit of function in some point(a) and  that we can use x=a with series